# Converting a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix into a form readable by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scipy

I have a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix which is the output from TfidfVectorizer() class. I know I can access the individual components of this matrix in this manner:

So if I have this matrix here:

```
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(lines)
```

I can access the individual components here:

```
tf_idf_matrix.data
tf_idf_matrix.indices
tf_idf_matrix.indptr
```

How do I save this from Python- such that I can load it into a MATLAB sparse matrix? OR how do I change it into a dense array, and save it as one numpy.ndarray text file - such that I can just simply load it into MATLAB as a matrix. The size of this matrix is not VERY large - its (5000, 68k)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `tf_idf_matrix.A` will give you a dense array constructed from your sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have those components in matlab
then

```
x = accumarray(indptr+1, ones(size(indptr)),[1,N]);
% N being the number of rows >= max indptr+1

colind = cumsum(x);
res = sparse(colind,indices,data);
```

should do it.

The first part just converts the `indptr` vector into a vector to match each index with the right column number. 
(note that `indptr` may have repititions and this is why the accumarray is necessary )

Comment: When I do accumarray, I get this error message: Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts. My indptr is a <4916 x 1 double> in MATLAB. Thanks for the input!

Comment: oops sorry, i did this without the dataset, indptr is 0 based should be indptr+1 on that first line . edited

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB sparse constructor:

> S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax) uses vectors i, j, and s to generate an m-by-n sparse matrix such that S(i(k),j(k)) = s(k), with space allocated for nzmax nonzeros

is the same as the scipy sparse (including the step of adding values with `ij` are same).

> csr_matrix((data, ij), [shape=(M, N)])
>   where data and ij satisfy the relationship a[ij[0, k], ij[1, k]] = data[k]

`data` and `ij` the attributes of the `coo_matrix` format. So for a start I'd suggest converting `tocoo` and writing the three arrays to a `.mat` file  (`scipy.io`).